# jordanmiguel/laravel-popular can't install

Tags: laravel

jordanmiguel/laravel-popular can't install

composer require jordanmiguel/laravel-popular

$ composer require jordanmiguel/laravel-popular
Using version ^1.0 for jordanmiguel/laravel-popular
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install jordanmiguel/laravel-popular v1.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install jordanmiguel/laravel-popular v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install jordanmiguel/laravel-popular v1.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install jordanmiguel/laravel-popular v1.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - Installation request for jordanmiguel/laravel-popular ^1.0 -> satisfiable by jordanmiguel/laravel-popular[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3

```
- don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
-
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit: As noted by the package author below, a new version has been tagged and released. You should now update your composer.json to stable releases again.

Although the code of that package has been updated to support Laravel 6, a new release has not been tagged or pushed. If you want to use it with Laravel 6 you will have to use dev-master as your version constraint

```
composer require jordanmiguel/laravel-popular:dev-master
```

Answer (score 1):

A new version has been tagged. You can just

```
composer require jordanmiguel/laravel-popular
```